# Microsoft graph API access tokens lifetime

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm having some trouble understanding how to get a Microsoft graph API token that lives more than 3599 seconds.

This is my first call to the API to get the first token:

[image]

And now that I got a refresh token I going to pass it through another call to get a new token:

[image]

This all works fine, except the new token also has a 3599 duration, so, my question is, is it possible to get a longer lived token, e.g. 14 days?

Comment: hi how did you generate the `code` parameter? thats not present in the Azure App that I created

Answer (score 8):

This actually isn't determined by Microsoft Graph but rather by Azure Active Directory.

For a given tenant, the life-time can be configured using [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). There are a couple of important notes about this functionality:

- This functionality is still in Preview, so functionality may change between now and general release.
- This configuration is per *tenant*, *service principal*, or *application*. If you configure it on the application, then the policy will apply on multi-tenant applications unless superseded by a policy on the service principal or tenant level.
- The maximum lifetime for an Access token is 24 hours (minimum is 10 minutes, default is 1 hour).

In general, rather than adjusting the lifetime of the Access Token you should rely on the Refresh Token instead. These have a much longer lifetime of 14 days.

Comment: Small correction Marc, the configuration can be set on the tenant, application, or service principal. If you set it on the app, then it will apply for multi-tenant solutions unless overridden by another policy. This is explained in detail in the doc you linked if you want more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your access token from short-time to long-time in the following way:

1. From the Developer page, click Tools -> Access token debugger
2. Here, drop your Access token then drag it down to the bottom. You will see the long-lived access token created.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you give an address or picture of "Developer page" ?